# How to change UISearchBar (inside of a tableview) to UIToolBar runtime?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a table view with searchbar. I would like to give the user options to turn on or off searchbar. When the searchbar is turned off, that area should display a UIToolBar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assign a tag to your searchBar

```
-(IBAction) searchbarOFF: (id) sender {

    [[urTableView viewWithTag:100] removeFromSuperview];

     //Add UIToolBar to your TableView here.
}
```